# Aauth - update_user() - Not sure how to use

Tags: php, codeigniter

Perhaps I'm just unsure on the documentation. I've tried to figure it out, but I've never used this Codeigniter library before (Aauth). I'm attempting to create a form / page that will allow a user to change their password. The form works fine, but it's not changing the users password in the database.

The documentation says this:

Please note that I am not sure what "FALSE" represents. I do not see a change password method in the documentation provided [here.](https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth/wiki/4)-User-Operations)

> update_user($user_id, $email = FALSE, $pass = FALSE, $name = FALSE)
>
> Updates user by using user_id

I'm not seeing any errors.

I'm writing something like this:

```
// get user info for currently logged user (this part works)
$userdata = $this->aauth->get_user();

// Change Password (not currently changing the password for the user)
$this->aauth->update_user($userdata->id, $userdata->email, $_POST['formpassword']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, didn't realize when it said "FALSE" it meant it was required.

The correct solution:

```
// I did not want to change email or name. Password only.

$this->aauth->update_user($userdata->id, FALSE, $_POST['formpassword'], FALSE);
```